# How can I curve a logo on a path without distorting it too much

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, distort

I've encountered a problem and I'm hoping there is going to be a quick fix involved, and that I wont have to redraw this logo:

[image]

The client wants to create a logo that curves on a tire like this:

[image]

I know about the type on path tool, but this is a custom font. Is there a way to turn this into a font and would that make it distort correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp > Arc` To curve the logo into a semi-circle.

[image]

Realize that the larger the diameter of the circle (tire) the less distorted the logo will appear. But some distortion is always present. If you don't want *any* distortion whatsoever, you need to redraw the logo on an arc rather than trying to make a logo fit an arc.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer converting the straight logo into an art brush and I would apply it to any curve.

[image]
[image]